# send multiple image + multiple array object to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
 function GetConfirmMedicine() {
            var PharmacyProductList = new Array();

            var medObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("phrmacyCart"));
            for (var i = 0; i < medObj.length; i++) {
                PharmacyProductList.push({
                    ProductID: medObj[i].ProductID,
                    ProductTitle: medObj[i].ProductTitle,
                    Quantity: medObj[i].Quantity,
                    TotalPrice: medObj[i].MedicinTotalPrice

                });
            }
            model = {
                FullName: $('#FullNametxt').val(),
                ContactNumber: $('#ContactNumbertxt').val(),
                Address: $('#Addresstxt').val(),
               // ImagePhath: $('#uploadFiletxxt')[0],

                PharmacyProductList: PharmacyProductList
            };
            return model;
        }

        function ConfirmOrder() {
            var file = $('#uploadFiletxxt')[0];
            var data = GetConfirmMedicine();

            //var data = JSON.stringify({ 'model': model });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + 'Home/PostPharmcyData',
                data: { imagePath: file, model: data },
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: false,
                //processData: false,
                success: function (response) {

                }
            })
        }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult PostPharmcyData(HttpPostedFileBase[] imagePath, PharmacyViewModel model)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Upload files using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](http://ajeeshms.in/articles/upload-files-using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/)

In your controller, you can use Request object to save the files.

Comment: how PharmacyProductList  would show ??? in controller VeiwModel                 [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult PostPharmcyData(HttpPostedFileBase[] imagePath, PharmacyViewModel model)
     }